# 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state

Tags: javascript, websocket

Иногда в обработчике события `WebSocket.open` при попытке отправить данные получаю такую ошибку -
`Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.`
Тестировал только на Google Chrome.

Не хочу велосипедить. Поэтому основной вопрос - как правильно обработать такую ситуацию? 
Для этой ошибки не срабатывает событие `WebSocket.error`, что и не удивительно. Непонятно почему событие `WebSocket.open` срабатывает до того как в сокет можно отправлять данные?

```
var socket = new WebSocket(config.server);
socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
socket.onopen = function () {
  socket.send(sid); // ошибка возникает только тут
};
```

Если после срабатывания `WebSocket.open` немного подождать и только потом впервые отправлять данные - ошибка не воспроизводится.

Comment: А Вы попробуйте проверять состояние соединения перед отправкой (readyState), и если оно открыто, только тогда отсылайте. А если оно открывается еще - то подождите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня была такая же ошибка. Исправил так:

```
var wsSend = function(data) {
    if(!ws.readyState){
        setTimeout(function (){
            wsSend(data);
        },100);
    }else{
        ws.send(data);
    }
};
wsSend(data);
```

Костыль конечно, но работает.

Answer (score 3):

Вы бинарные файлы отправлять будете или текст?
Вот например общение через json формат
Попробуйте по аналогии

```
          WebSocketConnect = function() {
          var Sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:80/websocket");
          try { 

              Sock.onopen = function(m) {  
                console.log("Соединение открыто...");
              }
              Sock.onmessage = function(m) { 
                    data_ =m['data']; 
                    data =JSON.parse(data_);
                    switch (data["Command"]) {
                      case 'Clients_List': 
                           //Тут действия,если пришла команда Clients_List
                      break  
                      case 'Client_Data_Changed': 
                          //Тут действия,если пришла команда Client_Data_Changed
                      break 

                      default:  
                             console.log("Функция не распознана");
                  }

              };
              Sock.onerror = function(m) {
                console.log('Ошибка подключения');
              };
              Sock.onclose = function(m) {
                      console.log("Соединение разорвано"); 
                setInterval(function() {
                  //Если jquery, то проверяем пинг с сервера и если всё ок, то либо реконектимся,либо перезапускаем страницу
                  $.ajax({url: '/api/ping',success: function(){
                    window.location.reload();
                  }});
                }, 5000);
              };

            } catch(exception) {
              console.log(exception);
            }
            return {
                    Command1: function(Site,param1){
                      var Send= {
                          "Command":"Command1",
                          "Data":{"Site":Site,"param1":param1}
                      };
                      Sock.send(JSON.stringify(Send));
                    },
                    Command2: function(){
                      var Send= {
                          "Command":"Command2"
                      };
                      Sock.send(JSON.stringify(Send));
                    }
            } 
    var connection= WebSocketConnect();
    connection.Command1("http://ukrtest.in.ua","param1"); //отсылаем какие-то данные
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Отправляю бинарные данные. Но суть не в этом. Приведенная в вопросе ошибка возникает исключительно для приведенного мной примера - если пытаться отправить данные в обработчике события `WebSocket.open`. Причем проявляется она крайне редко, раз на сотни удачных попыток, а иногда очень-очень редко может проявиться несколько раз  подряд (естественно каждый раз я перезагружаю страницу и тем самым создаю новое соединение). От загрузки сервера не зависит.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникает потому-что идет одновременное обращение из разных частей приложения, и пока одно открыло соединение и пытается отправить данные, другое переокрывает тоже самое соединение.
Если хотите использовать только один вебсокет, то создайте класс с [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) и сохраните его в свойстве

```
class Ws extends Object {
  get newClientPromise(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
      let wsClient = new WebSocket("ws://domen.com/ws");
      console.log(wsClient)
      wsClient.onopen = () => {
        console.log("connected");
        resolve(wsClient);
      };
      wsClient.onerror = (error)=>{ reject(error); };
    }
                      )
  }
  get clientPromise(){
    var stompClientPromise = this.stompClientPromise
    if (!stompClientPromise)
      stompClientPromise = this.newClientPromise
    this.stompClientPromise = stompClientPromise
    return stompClientPromise;
  }
}
```

создайте синглтон и используйте в любой части приложения

```
wsSingleton = new Ws()
wsSingleton.clientPromise
  .then( wsClient =>{wsClient.send('data'); console.log('sended')})
  .catch( error => alert(error) )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35p4ppbz/48/